Sitecore Search Scope or token - Multilist field with doesn't contain value
I have multiple pages based on the "Article" template, and all of them contain a Multilist field named "CustomTags." This field allows the selection of multiple values.
Currently, I am browsing a specific page and using a Search Results component to display related content. I am attempting to create a search scope that filters items based on the template name and the CustomTags field value using the SXA query:
  +sxa:ItemsWithTheSameValueInField|CustomTags;+template:{bf9b166a-b6f3-4a9f-9561-a218ed50dbf8};+sxa:ExcludeCurrentPage;sort:publishdate[desc]

Problem is, If the customtag field doesn't contains any selected field mean empty. i dont want to display component.

please suggest, anything is missing in the query

If I understand correctly you want to hide the component if the current page has no tags (as that makes no sense to search for related items).
Hiding the component should not be done based on your query though. You should use the personalization features. Add a personalization rule on your component that hides the component if the CustomTags field is empty. That should do the trick.

i have selected the field condition and value "what i need to use"

Your value should be empty I assume if you want to check on an empty field

as per sreekrishnan answer this that query is working for you!

Could you please try to use this modified query as shown below :
+sxa:ItemsWithTheSameValueInField|CustomTags;+template:{bf9b166a-b6f3-4a9f-9561-a218ed50dbf8};+sxa:ExcludeCurrentPage;+CustomTags:*;sort:publishdate[desc]

I have added +CustomTags:* which ensures only items with at least one value in the CustomTags field are included in the search results.
Please try this and update me on the results?

This is not working as expected. is that work for you..

@sreekrishan still i'm getting the result. if the field is empty
